# Can't compare two NSDates

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate

Confused here... I have two dates which I NSLog to console and get:
dates are `2011-03-30 13:33:57 +0000 - 2011-03-28 13:33:57 +0000`

One date is clearly later than the other...   However, in the code below it doesn't matter if I use `[dateUSERPREFS laterDate:dateXML]` or `[dateUSERPREFS earlierDate:dateXML]` I get "we get first IF" displaying in the console?

Any ideas?  Thanks,

```
NSDate *dateXML = [df dateFromString:last_modifiedXML];
NSDate *dateUSERPREFS = [df dateFromString:last_modifiedUSERPREFS];

NSLog(@"dates are %@ - %@", dateXML, dateUSERPREFS);

if ([dateUSERPREFS laterDate:dateXML]) {        
    NSLog(@"we get first IF");
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`[aDate laterDate:anotherDate]` returns an `NSDate`, not a `BOOL`. Specifically, it returns the later of the two dates.

You want to use `compare:` instead:

```
NSComparisonResult comparisonResult = [dateUSERPREFS compare:dateXML];
if (comparisonResult == NSOrderedAscending) {
    // case where dateUSERPREFS is before dateXML
} else if (comparisonResult == NSOrderedSame) {
    // both dates are the same
} else if (comparisonResult == NSOrderedDescending) {
    // this could have just been a plain else; dateUSERPrefs after dateXML
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `[dateUSERPREFS timeIntervalSinceDate:dateXML]` which gives you the (signed) number of seconds from `dateXML` to `dateUSERPREFS`.

Comment: +1.  alternatively timeIntervalSinceDate: gives you the difference in seconds (negative if the receiver is earlier).

Comment: Great thanks.  What if the the two dates were equal to each other though?

Answer (score 2):

[In the documentation, Apple says that laterDate returns the later of the two dates, not a BOOL statement.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

I'd do the following: subtract one date from the other and check if the value is more or less than zero. That'd tell you which is larger:

```
if ([dateXML timeIntervalSinceDate:dateUSERPREFS] > 0) {
    //Now you know that dateXML is larger than dateUSERPREFS
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`-[NSDate laterDate:]` returns an `NSDate *` not a `BOOL`, and this won't be `Null`, so the condition will always be true.

Try `-[NSDate compare:]` which has the signature:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSDate *)anotherDate
```

You can then compare the [`NSComparisonResult`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html) in your `if` condition, which is I believe what you are trying to achieve with the code in your question.

(Of course, you could continue to use `laterDate:` and just compare equality with the original object, but I feel `compare:` makes for more intuitive logic)